# Find the digit signif(2) is rounding to?

Tags: r

I have two vectors. One containing the mean of my list, one the standard deviation.

I want both numbers to be rounded to the same spot. And the rounding should depend on the standard deviation. It should round to two significant figures of it, if those are below 24, and to one if they would be 25 or bigger.

Here are examples, as this is really confusing:

```
2.30344 0.01223 -> 2.303 0.012
304.57231 1.35234 -> 304.6 1.3
204.43953 3.35234 -> 204 3
```

I know of the `round` function where I can enter the digits, which I would have to apply for both. I also know of the `signif`fuction where I could enter two digits, but how can I check if the first two digits then are smaller than 25? And how can I then figure out to what digit signif has decided to round?

Comment: All of your deviations are below 24. Do you mean *"the rounding should depend on the standard deviation **and the scale of the mean**"*?

Comment: As for the number of digits to the right of the decimal point that `signif` decided to retain, if `sigmas` is the vector of standard deviations, try `nchar(gsub("^.*\\.", "", as.character(signif(sigmas, 2))))`